# How to print some information in the terminal while running a graphics.h based C program?

Tags: c, bgi

This is my first question in StackOverflow so forgive me for my mistakes in asking the question if any. I am trying to learn to use `graphics.h` library in C programming language as a part of the course curriculum and I am having trouble printing some information to the terminal in Linux while using `libgraph`. The `printf()` function prints the given information in the `libgraph` window instead of the terminal whereas I want it to print the information to the Linux terminal. Here are my code and screenshot of the output of this code Screenshot:

DDA algorithm screenshot of `printf` problem:
[image: DDA algorithm screenshot of printf problem]

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<graphics.h> 

//Function for finding absolute value 
int abs (int n) 
{ 
    return ( (n>0) ? n : ( n * (-1))); 
} 

//DDA Function for line generation 
void DDA(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1) 
{ 
    // calculate dx & dy 
    int dx = X1 - X0; 
    int dy = Y1 - Y0; 

    // calculate steps required for generating pixels 
    int steps = abs(dx) > abs(dy) ? abs(dx) : abs(dy); 

    // calculate increment in x & y for each steps 
    float Xinc = dx / (float) steps; 
    float Yinc = dy / (float) steps; 

    // Put pixel for each step 
    float X = X0; 
    float Y = Y0; 
    for (int i = 0; i <= steps; i++) 
    { 
    printf("(%f,%f)",X,Y);
        putpixel (X,Y,RED);  // put pixel at (X,Y) 
        X += Xinc;           // increment in x at each step 
        Y += Yinc;           // increment in y at each step 
        delay(100);          // for visualization of line- 
                             // generation step by step 
    } 
} 

// Driver program 
int main() 
{ 
    int gd = DETECT, gm; 

    // Initialize graphics function 
    initgraph (&gd, &gm, "");    

    int X0 = 2, Y0 = 2, X1 = 14, Y1 = 16; 
    DDA(2, 2, 100, 100); 
    getch();
    return 0; 
}
```

What I want is that `printf` to print in the Linux terminal instead of the `libgraph` window.

Comment: You can store all the output you have do in a buffer and then print after you do `closegraph()`. There are other ways too, by duplicating the `1` fd before you `initgraph` and then writing to it.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya im sorry but i did not understand what you meant by duplicating 1 fd. Can you please explain it?

Comment: I don't have the exact version of the graphics library you are using, but can you try `write(1, "Hello world", 11);` and check where it prints the string?

Comment: This is MS DOS BGI library. How do you even get that to run on Linux? And more importantly _why_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some, if not all implementations of *libgraph* have this line in one of the header files:

```
#define printf grprintf
```

So, they redefine `printf` with a macro, and you can't use it *to print in the linux terminal*. But since they don't redefine other output functions, you can use e. g.

```
    fprintf(stdout, "(%f,%f)", X, Y), fflush(stdout);    // or stderr instead of stdout
```

or `puts` for constant strings.

Or, even simpler, you can `#undef printf` after the `#include<graphics.h>` to get back the normal behavior.